# Electron app won't open after compiling for Win32 x64

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron, 64-bit

I have an issue. I was creating an app with electron and when I compiled it to an .exe file it built, but haven't started/created a window on my laptop. I tried turning off my Windows Defender but that didn't help. Whenever I try to run it with my npm script `npm start` or `electron .` it works. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

I run the `npm run build` script which will execute 
`mkdir build && electron-packager build ISS-Live-Locator --platform=win32 --arch=x64`

I copied this `main.js` file from the electron documentation. And updated my app structure accordingly.

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Thank you!
Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build command seems wrong.

See [the docs](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager#from-the-command-line) of `electron-packager` for the command's signature:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=<platform> --arch=<arch> [optional flags...]
```

What you do in `mkdir build && electron-packager build ISS-Live-Locator --platform=win32 --arch=x64` is basically trying to use the newly created `build` folder as source directory. Therefore, your app should be empty and can't run.

Also, you should get `Unable to determine Electron version. Please specify an Electron version` error because you don't specify electron version.

Try this build command instead:

```
electron-packager . ISS-Live-Locator --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electronVersion=10.1.1
```

Comment: I'll try this now

Comment: Had same issue (I am also using Angular), apparently was building via `electron-builder` and not via `electron-packager`. After using @pergy solution works well.